# How to hide .env keys in production environment on AWS S3 bucket & Cloudfront

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, astrojs, .env

I am working on a project with a micro-frontend structure, which is a parent Astro app hosting child React apps. Technologies used are ReactJS, with dependencies like Vite and Webpack CLI, etc.

I am using Amazon Cognito, and putting the UserPoolId & ClientId in a .env file, in the parent Astro app.

The issue *is* once I have deployed to AWS S3 & CloudFront Distribution. The .env file is not committed to Gitlab, so the deployed CloudFront website doesn't know where to find the UserPoolId & ClientId.

I have been researching and can't seem to find a good method. I have considered setting Gitlab CI/CD pipeline variables for the UserPoolId & ClientId, but I'm not sure if that is good practice. Have also considered using dotenv, but I don't think that works for security in production environment, only in dev.

What should I do so the deployed CloudFront website could access the UserPoolId & ClientId in a secure way? What are the steps you have taken? Would love to hear your input!

Answer (score 0):

Its a best practice to not store secrets in files. This article may be useful, I have not tried.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/authorizationedge-how-to-use-lambdaedge-and-json-web-tokens-to-enhance-web-application-security/

It describes how you can put Cognito in **front** of CloudFront, and once the user signs-in, get the JWT Token generated by Cognito and have it validated at the nearest edge location by a Lambda function, specifically a Lambda@Edge deployment.

Once validated, the request is forwarded to the origin and access to the private content is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the sensitive variables using AWS Secrets Manager. The secrets can be injected as variable during pipeline executions.
Personally I'm using Jenkins for my CI/CD and we have fine-grained permissions so I just create a Jenkins secret text for simplification.
Or you can also mount the `.env` file from a secured volume, given that you are executing your app in a containerized environment.